# ECharts Baidu how to display labels in negative value as positive value?

Tags: echarts

I am using ECharts Baidu to generate charts. I am using a tornado chart to display the force of left and right arm. The force of the left arm is displayed at the left side and right arm at the right side. Is there a way display the negative value of the label and the axis as positive? I can always hide the axis value so as long as the solution can make the graph to display negative as positive label, I will mark it as solution.

https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/bar5.html#-en

```
var option= {
        title: {
        },
        grid: {
          top: '10%',
          bottom: '25%',
          left: '20%',
          right: '10%',
        },
        tooltip: { triggerOn: 'click' },
        xAxis: [
          {
            type: 'value',
            name: 'Newton',
            nameLocation: 'center',
            nameTextStyle: {
              padding: 10
            },
          }
        ],
        yAxis: [
          {
            axisTick: { show: false },
            data: ['FEB']
          }
        ],
        barWidth: 40,
        series: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'feb',
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'top',
              }
            },
            data: [{ value: Number(data2[0].left) * -1 }],  //the value is from the ajax call
            itemStyle: { color: 'gray' }
          },
          {
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'feb',
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'top'
              }
            },
            data: [Number(data2[0].right)],
            itemStyle: { color: '#F26718' },
          },
        ],
        textStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'black'
        }
      }
      chart.setOption(option);
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
label: {
    normal: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function (params) {
            return Math.abs(params.value[1]);
        }
    }   
}
```

this example assumes that the data you passed to the chart is an array like [x, y]. if your input data is different, put a breakpoint inside the formatter function e see how "params" is structured.